# How to run android wear emulator connected with real android phone in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am developing an android watch application. I don't have physical watch device. In order to run, I'm connecting my physical phone with emulator watch to test it. But, after clicking on run application, it gives 'missing watch' error.

I have followed all the steps from this link (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49586/how-do-i-connect-an-android-wear-emulator-to-a-real-phone/) and in my android wear application, the emulator status is showing 'Connected'.

Can anyone please tell me how to run wear emulator connected with android real mobile device in android studio?

[image]

Comment: you should test on emulator directly. select watch emulator. it this pic you try to install wear app on phone so  you get the error.

Comment: Actually I'm connecting to web services through my phone, retreiving the data and posting on watch. So, when  I click on 'Get Data' in watch.. phone receives the data event from the watch and passes the initial message to the phone to display it in the container. If I select watch emulator, I am not seeing any application opening in my phone to see that data.

Comment: Do I first need to select 'mobile' and then install the apk on my mobile phone and then select 'watch' to see the connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Select the `Android Wear Round Chin API 26` on that dialog what you show. You start the companion app on the phone, and the wear part on the Wear (emulator or physical device). Then you'll see if it's really connected as soon as you try to communicate with the companion app.